# Unable to import "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent" in AWS-Lambda project

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm triggering a lambda function when my sqs standard queue receives a new message.
I need to give input type as `SQSEvent` in my request handler.
But I'm not able to import the package `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent` in my lambda project in eclipse.
Can any one faced the same issue previously.
Can any one suggest me how can I import this package in my lambda project.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you not able to import the package? Did you add the package to your dependency manager (maven/ant)?

Comment: @ChrisNeve I'm new to java and eclipse,I have installed `aws toolkit` in eclipse. 
 can you help me with the dependencies need to be added to import this package.

Comment: @ChrisNeve Thank you, that helped me.. I have updated my package with the 'aws-lambda-java-events-2.2.2` version, now I'm able to get the `SQSEvent` class.